# java ByteBuffer to int array conversion fails with UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

When converting a `ByteBuffer` to an `int` array java unexpectedly throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

However as a `byte` array the information is correctly represented.

```java
int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2};
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(intArray.length * 4);
IntBuffer ib = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
ib.put(intArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteBuffer.array())); // prints [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ib.array())); // Fails with exception UnsupportedOperationException
```

Reading through other posts I saw this exception in case there was no array to back up the `ByteBuffer`, but in this case the buffer has enough bytes allocated and should be able to return an `int[]`.

Why is this exception thrown?

(Using java11)

Comment: Please check that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19624671/13523946

Comment: “…should be able to return an `int[]`.”  You seem to be under the impression that the `array()` method *converts* the buffer’s contents to an array, like Collection.toArray or Stream.toArray, but that is not the case.  As Slaw explained, it returns the array that directly backs the buffer;  if the buffer wasn’t created directly from an int array, you get an UnsupportedOpertaionException.

Comment: But how would it be possible to transform a Bytebuffer into an int array without allocating new memory?

Comment: It's not possible to transform a `ByteBuffer` to an `int[]` without allocating new memory for the `int[]`. The best you could do is make use of the `IntBuffer` you created via `#asIntBuffer()`. Obviously, that allocates memory for the `IntBuffer` instance, but both the `ByteBuffer` and the `IntBuffer` will be backed by the same `byte[]` instance.

Answer (score 2):

The `#array()` methods of all the buffer classes are defined to throw `UnsupportedOperationException`:

> If this buffer is not backed by an accessible array

Also, modifying the array returned by `#array()` *modifies the buffer*:

> Modifications to this buffer's content will cause the returned array's content to be modified, and vice versa.

And you're calling it on an `IntBuffer` that was created via [`ByteBuffer#asIntBuffer()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asIntBuffer()), which:

> Creates a **view** *[emphasis added]* of this byte buffer as an int buffer.
>
> The content of the new buffer will start at this buffer's current position. **Changes to this buffer's content will be visible in the new buffer, and vice versa** *[emphasis added]*; the two buffers' position, limit, and mark values will be independent.
>
> *[...]*

Combine all that information and you can see why calling `array()` on your `IntBuffer` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. If it were to return an `int[]`, then changing the `int[]` would not be capable of modifying the `ByteBuffer`. This is a problem, because modifying the `int[]` is defined to modify the `IntBuffer`, and since your `IntBuffer` is only a view, modifying the `IntBuffer` is defined to also modify the `ByteBuffer`. But it's not possible to directly "link" a `byte[]` and an `int[]`, hence the operation is not supported.